# Any way to use a dylib dynamic library as static, or compile it into a new binary?

Tags: ios, ios9, dylib, dynamic-library

I'm doing some iOS development, and there's a tool I'd like to use for debugging. Unfortunately, the tool was not compiled to be compatible with iOS9 (dylibs used on iOS9 must be linked with sealign,4000 or they will not load). The app developer is horrendously slow to reply to use requests, so while I wait I'm investigating if I can find an alternative.

I have the .dylib. I do not have the source code. IOS 9 refuses to load the dylib because the segment alignment is not right. I've looked at it in IDA and Hopper but neither seem to offer a way to re-align it (which is infuriating, as I can rebase the program - I just cannot save it afterwards).

The only possible option left I can think of is to somehow wrap the dynamic library inside a static one. I don't even care how. Is there ANY possible way to convert it, unlink it, use libtool or objfile to change it, compile it into another binary and wrap each function by memory address? Anything? Waiting 2 months for an answer is my alternative. I'd like to get this done. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From all the research I've done, it is not possible to do, at all. Only option is to recompile from source code.